# Removing special format numeric values in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The Record looks likes this

**Current Value**
 - 1. Chair
 - 2. Table
 - 8 Port Switch
 - 3. Cable
....

**Desired Value**

- Chair
- Table
- 8 Port Switch
- Cable
  .....

I have tried the expression

```
SUBSTRING([Column], PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', [Column]), LEN([Column]))
```

and its works fine removing the numeric values from the start of the record but I want it to skip the numeric from **8 Port Switch** record.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following expression worked out for me....

```
Replace([Column],LEFT([Column],Charindex('.',[Column],-1)),'')
```

Thanks

Comment: @fabulaspb, you are right but the '-' was list item and included mistakenly. Appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

One option is just to fetch those rows that actually start with the number:

```
select ... where column like '[0-9]. %'
```

This of course works only with single digit numbers, but you'll probably have to make more complex logic for handling 2-digit numbers anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I've also removed first two chars ("- ").

```
DECLARE @test_table TABLE (value NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @test_table
SELECT '- 1. Chair'
UNION ALL
SELECT '- 2. Table'
UNION ALL
SELECT '- 8 Port Switch'
UNION ALL
SELECT '- 3. Cable'
UNION ALL
SELECT '- 14. Router'

SELECT SUBSTRING(value, PATINDEX('%[0-9].%', value) + 2, LEN(value))
FROM @test_table
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(MY_TEXT, '^-\s*[0-9]+\s*\.*\s*') AS MY_TEXT
FROM
(
    SELECT '- 1. Chair'      AS MY_TEXT FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '- 2. Table'      AS MY_TEXT FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '- 8 Port Switch' AS MY_TEXT FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '- 3. Cable'      AS MY_TEXT FROM DUAL
)
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(MY_TEXT, '^-\s*[0-9]+\s*\.*\s*') != 'Port Switch'
```

**Output of this is:**

> Chair
>
> Table
>
> Cable